# Is it possible to use Bluetooth A2DP/AVRCP with an online media player?

Tags: html, audio, bluetooth, jwplayer

Do any mobile browsers support sending Bluetooth metadata? Is it possible to do this with JW Player?

I've been researching, but I can only find references to Cordova plugins.